# How to change WordPress Comment output via hooks accessing comment meta data?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, arguments, hook-wordpress

I am looking to add some meta data to my Woo Commerce product reviews.

My plugin shows which product *variant* the customer is reviewing, and I wanted to add that information into each of the customer's reviews (comments), with a small thumbnail img of the product varient to fancy things up a bit as well.

But I am having trouble finding a filter / hook to tap into.

I have tried this one...

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', function( string $comment_text ) {

    $comment_text = '<p>Comment text injection</p>' . $comment_text;

    return $comment_text;
});
```

It works, but the problem is , it does not provide much context... I need the comment ID so I can grab some meta data about the comment.

The documentation says it is possible to for this filter to have a WP_Comment obj passed with the filter... but that doesn't happen in my case.

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text/)

Any suggestions on hooks/filters available to use - I don't really want to have to start hacking the comments template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`comment_text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text/) filter hook allow 3 function arguments (so you missed 2 of them):

- `$comment_text` (string), the main filtered argument
- `$comment` (object), the current `WP_Comment` Object instance
- `$args` (array), an array of arguments

So in this hooked function, here is an example targeting Order notes for example:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'customizing_comment_text', 20, 3 );
function customizing_comment_text( $comment_text, $comment, $args ) {
    if( $comment->comment_type === 'review' ) {
        $comment_text = '<p>Comment text injection</p>' . $comment_text;
    }
    return $comment_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

---

**To get specific comment meta data** you will use the function [`get_comment_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta) like:

```
$meta_value = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'your_meta_key', true );
```

**To Add specific comment meta data** you will use the function [`add_comment_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta) like:

```
add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'your_meta_key', $meta_value, $unique );
```

Comment: If I use the function with the extra arguments, I get an exception stating only 1 argument was passed.

Comment: @DaleWoods That is not normal… see the related documentation for this hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text/ So there is 3 arguments and you need to specify the hook priority and number of arguments like in my example.

Comment: Yes I linked that url in my question. That's why I am confused why those variables are not being passed when I call that filter.

Comment: @DaleWoods I have updated lightly my code for product reviews and tested that. It works perfectly (see the screenshot)…

Comment: My mistake was not passing the 10, 3 at the end of add_filter for letting wordpress know there will be 3 variables passed to the filter.